# D-Link WLan conncetion problems

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have a d-link wlan router at home. It hasn't had a password for a while, but a few weeks ago I decided to add one. I choose WPA2 personal with AES. Since then I have problems to connect to the WLan, with different Laptops. I am using Win7, all properties are correct, if I use the wrong password i get another error. When I try to connect it tries that for some time and the says it is not possible to connect. I have to try it again a few times and then it works. On another laptop with win8 the same problem. And there, sometimes it connects, but the connection is restricted, no internet access.

If I am finally connected the ping sometimes gets high for a few seconds ( > 1000) and is most times at about 200. It seems like at noon the ping is normal (at about 60-80). This is why I thought it could be, that the wlan channel is occupied by some other routers in the neighbourhood. Could that be the problem? Is the ping higher if the channel is occupied? And are there also problems with the connection if that happens? Or could that be another problem?

I do not have a lot of knowledge about this things so I am sorry if I did not give enough informations!

**EDIT**: yesterday i tryed to ping the router. I got 1-2ms ping. So the Wlan is not the reason for the hight ping right? I did not change the WPA2 password to WPA/WPA2 mixed mode, as i did not had any issues while connecting. It just seems to occure randomly...
Also i searched for other networks in the neighbourhood with the free android app `Wifi Analyzer`. I have only found my own and one other, on different channels. On the laptop i find another one, with a hidden SSID, so the Wifi analyzer can't show that. But i don't think that the channels are a problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it could be several different issues.
Try checking few things:

- Make sure that WLAN works fine when you turn WPA2-Personal verification off again, if yes:
- Unplug your router for 1 min, then turn it ON again
- Use tools like inSSIDer to check channel on which your router works; it's not directly connected to your issue, but as you mentioned ping issues, you can take a look on it too
- Try WPA/WPA2 mixed mode with AES - maybe both computers have problems with WPA2 verification on router (it's weird though)
- If you manage to connect router, check in your network settings what verification type your computer picked. You can also try forcing WPA2+AES if you're computer forces something else.

If it won't change anything, consider borrowing router from someone and check if your computer behave normally while connecting to WPA2+AES network (or just take laptop and router to someone and - as you would normally do on StackOverflow - debug!).
You will then have a clue if it's rather router related issue or your computers' related issue.

Right know I'm afraid it's the only thing I can advise according to the info you provided.
Also, for other people trying to help: please provide model of your WLAN Router.
Please also specify wheter wired connections are working after enabling WPA2 (should not be connected to wireless issues but from my experience - sometimes it is).

Comment: I am not at home right now, this is why i don't know the exact model. The issue occured only since the password has been enabled, with the ping i am not sure if it is also since then. But if the computers do not support WPA2 they would never connect and not only sometimes right?

Comment: Well, I didn't say they do not support WPA2 but rather encounter problems when using it. My guess it's problem with the verification that router serves and so computers have problem to - let's say - understand it.

Comment: So should i try using WPA? And AES or TKIP?

Comment: Try mixed mode (WPA/WPA2) and see if it changes anything. I wrote you that above. :)

Comment: Ah okay did not know that a mixed mode exists xD I will try that. Thanks

Comment: Hi. I updated my question, cause i tryed something yesterday. Check it out please.

Comment: Ok, it seems that router is your main problem. Also I mentioned channels for ping issues, not connection issues. :)
Can you please provide model of your router?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13120/discussion-between-springrbua-and-battlefist)

Comment: The ping should be a) The cable from the line to the router or b) the line/ a provider issue. This we need to test. The connection problem occures only sometimes, randomly and after connecting a few times it workes. But this is only since we added a password. So you think that is a router problem? As i said i did not change the password to Mixedmode, because yesterday i had no problems with it.

Comment: The connection problem does not happen verry often now. Maybe the router had a problem, but now it is okay. The ping problem should be from provider site. Thanks for your quick and clear answer. Accepted.

Comment: A qucik update: it seems, that the D-Link modem had some problems with the DHCP. As soon as we used a fixed ip for all clients in the network we had no more problems wit hthe connection. It seems, like the D-Link could not give you unused ips, even if the DHCP had at least 100 unused IPs.